# Movilizer for SAP - Create horizontal menu

Tags: abap, movilizer

Is it possible to create an horizontal menu screen in Movilizer? How?

I've seen it done in XML trough this link:
https://devtools.movilizer.com/confluence/display/DOC24/Basic+Image+Menu+screen

But how can I do that in SAP?

Comment: This depends on what your approach is in your SAP integration. Are you trying your own scenario implementation on top of the connector?

Comment: Yes, I'm creatingmy own scenario André.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image menu/selection screen by appending of screen into **ES_MOVELET-IMAGESEL_SCREENS** of **GENERATE** method.

there you have to select **IS_MENU** flag in case if you need a menu screen (if it is blank - image select screen will be rendered).

Needed menu items must be added to **ANSWERS**

Comment: Hello Vitali, I don't want to add any image. I just want to create a menu with some buttons displayed horizontally.

Comment: Horizontal menus are currently only possible via image menu (type="13") or image select screens (type = "7").